# How to setup REST server to communicate with Hyperledger Fabric consortium on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, azure-aks, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js, azure-blockchain-workbench, azure-blockchain-service

I set up hyperledger fabric on [Hyperledger Fabric consortium on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/templates/hyperledger-fabric-consortium-azure-kubernetes-service#create-channel-command)
. I have installed [this chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/artifacts/src/github.com/example_cc/go/example_cc.go) on the network. I have tested `peer invoke` and `peer query` command on azure-cli. It is working properly. Now I want to communicate with this hyperledger network using [this REST API server](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/balance-transfer). Help me to set up this REST Server.

Edited:
I edited [this config file](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/artifacts/network-config.yaml) with the following way. But no luck.

```
---
name: "balance-transfer"
x-type: "hlfv1"
description: "Balance Transfer Network"
version: "1.0"
#
# The client section will be added on a per org basis see org1.yaml and org2.yaml
#
#client:
#
# [Optional]. But most apps would have this section so that channel objects can be constructed
# based on the content below. If an app is creating channels, then it likely will not need this
# section.
#
channels:
  mychannel:
    orderers:
      - orderer1.OrdererOrg
    peers:
      peer1.org1:
        endorsingPeer: true
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: true

      peer2.org1:
        endorsingPeer: false
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: false
    chaincodes:
      - mycc:v0
organizations:
  Org1:
    mspid: org1

    peers:
      - peer1.org1
      - peer2.org1
    certificateAuthorities:
      - ca-org1
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: ./artifacts/azure/peer/adminPrivateKey
    signedCert:
      path: ./artifacts/azure/peer/signcerts.pem
orderers:
  orderer1.OrdererOrg:
    url: grpcs://orderer1.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.eastus.aksapp.io:443
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: orderer1.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.eastus.aksapp.io

    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./artifacts/azure/orderer/ca.crt
peers:
  peer1.org1:
    url: grpcs://peer1.YYYYYYYYYYYYYY.eastus.aksapp.io:443

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer1.YYYYYYYYYYYYYY.eastus.aksapp.io
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./artifacts/azure/peer/peer1_ca.crt

  peer2.org1:
    url: grpcs://peer2.TTTTTTTTTTTTT.eastus.aksapp.io:443
    eventUrl: grpcs://peer2.TTTTTTTTTTTTT.eastus.aksapp.io:443
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: peer2.VVVVVVVVVV.eastus.aksapp.io
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./artifacts/azure/peer/peer2_ca.crt
certificateAuthorities:
  org1CA:
    url: https://ca.ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ.eastus.aksapp.io:443
    httpOptions:
      verify: false
    tlsCACerts:
      path: ./artifacts/azure/org/org1.pem
    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw
    caName: ca.org1
```

connection profile for org1

```
{
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "org1CA": {
            "caName": "ca.org1",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "pem1"
            },
            "url": "https://ca.m.eastus.aksapp.io:443"
        }
    },
    "client": {
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "orderer": "300",
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        },
        "organization": "org1"
    },
    "name": "org1",
    "organizations": {
        "org1": {
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "org1CA"
            ],
            "mspid": "org1",
            "peers": [
                "peer1.org1",
                "peer2.org1"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer1.org1": {
            "grpcOptions": {
                "hostnameOverride": "peer1.x.eastus.aksapp.io",
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.x.eastus.aksapp.io"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "pem"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://peer1.x.eastus.aksapp.io:443"
        },
        "peer2.org1": {
            "grpcOptions": {
                "hostnameOverride": "peer2.x.eastus.aksapp.io",
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer2.x.eastus.aksapp.io"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "pem"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://peer2.x.eastus.aksapp.io:443"
        }
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "wallet": "org1"
}
```

Connection profile for orderer.

```
{
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "OrdererOrgCA": {
            "caName": "ca.OrdererOrg",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "pem"
            },
            "url": "https://ca.x.eastus.aksapp.io:443"
        }
    },
    "client": {
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "orderer": "300",
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        },
        "organization": "OrdererOrg"
    },
    "name": "OrdererOrg",
    "organizations": {
        "OrdererOrg": {
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "OrdererOrgCA"
            ],
            "mspid": "OrdererOrg",
            "orderers": [
                "orderer1.OrdererOrg",
                "orderer2.OrdererOrg",
                "orderer3.OrdererOrg"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer1.OrdererOrg": {
            "grpcOptions": {
                "hostnameOverride": "orderer1.x.eastus.aksapp.io",
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer1.x.eastus.aksapp.io"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "pem"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://orderer1.x.eastus.aksapp.io:443"
        },
        "orderer2.OrdererOrg": {
            "grpcOptions": {
                "hostnameOverride": "orderer2.x.eastus.aksapp.io",
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer2.x.eastus.aksapp.io"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "pem"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://orderer2.x.eastus.aksapp.io:443"
        },
        "orderer3.OrdererOrg": {
            "grpcOptions": {
                "hostnameOverride": "orderer3.x.eastus.aksapp.io",
                "ssl-target-name-override": "orderer3.x.eastus.aksapp.io"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "pem"
            },
            "url": "grpcs://orderer3.x.eastus.aksapp.io:443"
        }
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "wallet": "OrdererOrg"
}
```

Comment: We have written our own sample REST service here: https://github.com/Azure/Hyperledger-Fabric-on-Azure-Kubernetes-Service/tree/master/azhlfTool using Typescript. You can take the reference of this open-source repository to identify HLF native functions that are useful in performing required operations for your HLF network running on AKS.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any REST Server in node js. I am not aware of typescript.

Comment: You can take the reference HLF functions, as those would be that of Node.js v1.4.4. For creating a REST server directly in Node.js, you can probably take help of `express` and check its native syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy REST API server as indepedent pod (using deployment) in kubernetes. You will need to provide configuration of network using `TARGET_NETWORK` environment variable. This configuration can be added as file as instructed in `Network configuration considerations` section of README file of server.

Steps involved would be

1. Creating docker image for the API Server and push to ACR reporitory.
2. Create deployment yaml file to deploy this docker image (with environment variable for network)
3. Create service of type `LoadBalancer` in kubernetes which creates the load balancer in azure which would allow to make http calls.

Special attention would be needed to connect to hyberledger network using environment variable and file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. My problem is how to configure (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer/artifacts/network-config.yaml) REST Sever (https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.4/balance-transfer) to communicate with Hyperledger Fabric consortium on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).

Comment: As mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/blockchain/templates/hyperledger-fabric-consortium-azure-kubernetes-service, there should be nginx configured which can be used by client for outside communication, did you try using hostname of the nginx for communication? I am not an expert in hyperledger, hence these might be ne expact solution.